# EF7 'dnx ef update database' not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta7. If I want to update my database with  'dnx ef update database' I get a 'done'. But nothing happend.
Is there a way to manually (in code) start the migration and debug it?

Update: no it works

1. I moved the mode back to the web project,
2. called 'dnvm install latest'
3. called 'dnx ef database update -c myContext' because I have more

Comment: Have you tried context.Database.Migrate() ?

Comment: yes, it did not work

Comment: I installed localdb 2014 and now it works for a standard web template. In my project I have two connectionstrings and a model project. I try to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

I meet a same issue in EF RC1. and i have a finding, hope it can help you.
i create a project to involve entity model and EF DBContext. then web project reference the project.
run these commands, not working:

1. dnx ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
2. dnx ef database update
   [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftbey.png)

but when i move the DBContext class to my web project, models still in other project, it working fine.[New result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgMbG.png)

so in my scenario need make sure DBContext in Web project.

Answer (score 0):

****Database Migration in Entity Framework 7 Asp.net 5 Mvc 6****

run cmd

1. C:>Path of  Project>dnvm install -1.0.0-rc1-final
2. C:>Path of Project>dnvm use -1.0.0-rc1-final
3. C:>Path of  Project>dnx ef migrations add InitialMigration
4. C:>path of  Project>dnx ef database update

if you use multiple DbContext then we need to specify Dbcontext

1. C:>Path of  Project>dnvm install -1.0.0-rc1-final
2. C:>Path of     Project>dnvm use -1.0.0-rc1-final
3. C:>Path of  Project>dnx ef migrations add InitialMigration -c DataContext
4. C:>path of  Project>dnx ef database update -c DataContext

Answer (score 0):

If your project is `A` and you put your `DbContext` in a separate class library say `B`, you need to append `.MigrationsAssembly("A")` after `UseSqlServer(...)` in the Startup.cs, please refer to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3840